# $L/K$ unramified at $v$ and $\widetilde{K}$ intermediate field $\Rightarrow\, \widetilde{K}/K$ unramified at $v$

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification, galois-extensions

Let $K$ be a number field, $L$ a field with $K\subset L\subset\mathbb{C}$ and $L/K$ Galois (not necessarily finite).

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $L/K$ be unramified at a finite place $v$ and $\widetilde{K}$ an intermediate field $K\subset\widetilde{K}\subset L$ with $\widetilde{K}/K$ Galois, then $\widetilde{K}/K$ is unramified at $v$.

I think I know how to prove this for $L/K$ finite:

Let $p\subset\mathcal{O}_K$ be the prime associated to the finite place $v$. Since $L/K$ is unramified at $v$, then $p\mathcal{O}_L$ has the form $p\mathcal{O}_L=\mathfrak{P}_1...\mathfrak{P}_r$, where $\mathfrak{P}_1,...,\mathfrak{P}_r$ are primes above $p$. Letting $\mathfrak{Q}_i:=\mathfrak{P}_i\cap\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{K}}$, we get:

$$p\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{K}}=p\mathcal{O}_L\cap\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{K}}=\mathfrak{Q}_1...\mathfrak{Q}_r$$

Therefore $p$ is unramified at $\widetilde{K}$, which is what we want.

Is this true for $L/K$ infinite? How do I prove it?

Comment: What is your definition of $p$ being unramified in an infinite extension? Do you know what the inertia group is?

Comment: @Mathmo123, if $w$ is a finite place (at $L$) above $v$ (at $K$), the inertia group of $w|v$ is $I_{w|v}=\{\sigma\in Gal(L_w/K_v)\mid \sigma(a)\equiv a (mod\, m_w)\,\forall\,a\in\mathcal{O}_w\}$, where $m_w$ is the maximal ideal associated to $w$. We say $L/K$ is unramified at $v$ when $I_{w|v}$ is trivial for all $w$ above $v$, right?

Comment: That's right. Now all you need to do is show that if $w'$ is a prime of $\widetilde K$ such that $w'\mid w$, then the restriction map $I_{w/v}\to I_{w'/v}$ is surjective.

Comment: @Mathmo123, when I take $\sigma\in I_{w|v}$, how do I know that 
 the restricition $\sigma|_{\widetilde{K}}$ is an automorphism of $\widetilde{K}$?

Comment: Because $\widetilde K/K$ is Galois!

Comment: @Mathmo123, I've verified that $I_{w|v}\to I_{w'|v}$ is well-defined and that $Gal(\widetilde{K}_{w'}/K_v)\triangleleft Gal(K_w/K_v)$. But I don't know how to prove surjectiveness, unless the extensions are finite.

Comment: I would like to solve this question.  But I don't understand what you mean by a "finite place" of $L$ lying over $v$.  Nor do I understand what is meant by the completion $L_w$.  If $L/K$ is not a finite extension, then $\mathcal O_L$, the integral closure of $\mathcal O_K$, need not be a Dedekind domain, or even Noetherian.  It's not clear how primes of $\mathcal O_L$ correspond to absolute values (which would give you completions).

Comment: @AguirreK You have the direction wrong. $\mathrm{Gal}(\widetilde{K}_{w'}/K_v)$ is a quotient, not a subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(K_w/K_v)$

Comment: @Mathmo123, ignore what I said about $Gal(\widetilde{K}_{w'}/K_v)$, I just know that $I_{w|v}\to I_{w'|v}$ is well-defined.

Comment: @D_S It's a poor choice of notation, but it's not so bad. Given an infinite extension $K$ of $\mathbb Q$, it makes sense to consider a prime above $p$, and to consider elements modulo that prime. Doing so is necessary to define the decomposition and inertia group.

Comment: @AguirreK The point is that by Galois theory, if $M/L/K$ are all Galois, then $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K) \cong\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)/\mathrm{Gal}(M/L)$. The isomorphism is given by the restriction map

Comment: @Mathmo123 I didn't know this holds for infinite Galois extensions! Would you give me some good reference for infinite Galois Theory?

Comment: I don't have one off the top of my head, but a search for infinite galois theory gives some good results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tilde{\nu}$ be a prime in $\tilde{K}$ over $\nu$, and let $\beta$ be a prime over $\tilde{\nu}$, we have to prove that the restriction from $I_{\nu}^{\beta}$ to $I_{\nu}^{\tilde{\nu}}$ is surjective.

Consider the sets $A=\{I_{\nu}^{\mathfrak{a}_M}:\mathfrak{a}_{M}\subset \beta,\ \mathfrak{a}_M\ \text{is a prime over }\nu\ \text{of a finite Galois extension } M/K,\ M\subset L\}$ and 
$B=\{I_{\nu}^{\mathfrak{p}_N}:\ \mathfrak{p}_N\subset \tilde{\nu}, \ \mathfrak{p}_N\ \text{is a prime over }\nu \text{ of a finite Galois extension } N/K,\ N\subset \tilde{K}\}$.

This sets are ordered by $I_{\nu}^{\mathfrak{a}_{N_i}}\leq I_{\nu}^{\mathfrak{a}_{N_j}}$ if $N_i\subset N_j$, and 
if $I_{\nu}^{\mathfrak{a}_{N_i}}\leq I_{\nu}^{\mathfrak{a}_{N_j}}$ you have the restriction map, $Res:I_{\nu}^{\mathfrak{a}_{N_j}}\rightarrow I_{\nu}^{\mathfrak{a}_{N_i}}$, this restriction map is surjective because we are dealing with finite Galois extensions. You can prove these are projective systems and that $\lim\limits_{\leftarrow}A=I_{\nu}^{\beta}$ and $\lim\limits_{\leftarrow}B=I_{\nu}^{\tilde{\nu}}$.

This means that $I_{\nu}^{\tilde{\nu}}\cong \{(\sigma_{N})_N\in\prod\limits_{K\subset N\subset \tilde{K}} I_N: \sigma_{N_i}=\sigma_{N_j}|_{N_i}\}$ and that $I_{\nu}^{\beta}\cong\{(\sigma_{M})_M\in\prod\limits_{K\subset M\subset L} I_M: \sigma_{M_i}=\sigma_{M_j}|_{M_i}\}$.

Since the restriction map between inertia groups of finite Galois extensions is surjective, the projections in the above product are surjective, and this means that the restriction $Res I_{\nu}^\beta\rightarrow I_{\nu}^{\mathfrak{p}_M}$ is surjective for any $M$ finite Galois subextension and $\mathfrak{p}_M$ a prime of $M$ with $\mathfrak{p}_M\subset \beta$.

With this you can see that the restriction from $I_{\nu}^{\beta}$ to $I_{\nu}^{\tilde{\nu}}$ is surjective.